# Testing service with angular-mocks/jasmine - TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

Im trying to test a simple service in my angular app, using jasmine/karma/phantomJS.

jasmine version: 2.4.1
angular/angular-mocks: 1.5.7
phantomJS: 2.1.1

QueryParameters.service.tests.js : (QueryParameters.service.js is part of the app.service module, and is actually a **factory**, not a service)

```
describe('myApp.QueryParametersService', function() {

  var QueryParametersService;

  beforeEach(module('myApp'));
  beforeEach(module('app.service'));
  beforeEach(inject(function ($injector) {
    QueryParametersService = $injector.get('QueryParametersService');
  }));

  var testObject = {
    name : 'Hans',
    age  : '27'
  };

  it('Should output correct querystrings', function() {
    expect(QueryParametersService.toQueryParams(testObject)).toBe('?name=Hans&age=27');
  });

});
```

QueryParametersService.js:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app.service')
    .factory('QueryParametersService', QueryParametersService);

  QueryParametersService.$inject = [];

  function QueryParametersService() {

    var service = {
      toQueryParams : toQueryParams
    };

    return service;

    function toQueryParams(queryObject) {
      <removed code here>
    }
  }
})();
```

In Gruntfile.js:

```
karma: {
      unit: {
        options: {
          frameworks: ['jasmine'],
          singleRun: true,
          browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
          files: [
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/app.js',
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/filters/filter.module.js',
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/directives/directive.module.js',
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/services/service.module.js',
            '<%= yeoman.client %>/app/services/tests/*.js'
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

my main module (in app.js) is declared like this:

```
  angular.module('myApp', [
    'angular-thumbnails',
    'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination',
    'app.directive',
    'app.filter',
    'app.service',
    'color.picker',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngFileUpload',
    'ngImgCrop',
    'ngMaterial',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngResource',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ui.router',
    'validation.match',
  ])
```

The error im getting when running the tests:

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) myApp.QueryParametersService Should output correct querystrings FAILED
        /<filepath>/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4632:53
        forEach@/<filepath>/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:321:24
        loadModules@/<filepath>/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4592:12
        createInjector@/<filepath>/client/bower_components/angular/angular.js:4514:30
        workFn@/<filepath>/client/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:3067:60
        TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'QueryParametersService.toQueryParams') in /<filepath>/client/app/services/tests/query-parameters.service.tests.js (line 65)
        /<filepath>/client/app/services/tests/query-parameters.service.tests.js:65:34
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.002 secs / 0.009 secs)
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Looks like QueryParametersService.js is not included in the karma.conf.js files?

Comment: It is included here:
'<%= yeoman.client %>/app/services/service.module.js',

Comment: Actually, @jchen86 , you were right. I thought including the whole service module would be sufficient, but specifically including the service solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jchen86 pointed out, QueryParametersService.js wasn't included in the configuration (I thought it would be included when I included the whole service module). Solved by changing the gruntfile to include all js files in the service folder:

```
'<%= yeoman.client %>/app/services/*.js'
```